# BindData to ITemplate for GridView in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemplate

How do I programmatically bind data to a custom item template column for a GridView? So far, I've done something similar to this:

```
        TemplateField foo = new TemplateField();
        foo.ItemTemplate = new bar();
        this.GridView1.Columns.Add(foo);
```

where bar is like this:

```
public class bar : ITemplate
{
    public bar()
    {

    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        container.Controls.Add(ddl);
    }
}
```

(the actual dropdownlist is populated)

But ITemplate doesn't contain any kind of data binding properties to implement, and the TemplateField class doesn't seem to have any either...

What do I do?

---

Edit:  The other half is being able to handle the updates to get back to the original datasource.  If I just handle the rowupdate events, I don't see my TemplateColumn in the oldvalues/newvalues lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You handle the [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.

This explains things...
http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/dropdownlist-gridview-csharp.aspx

Comment: What about for Updates?  If I handle the RowDataUpdating event, I can't see my template column for updating the data source